# JS - Find x,y of middle of black square in image

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of images like this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYX1j.png

I need to find the x,y of the middle of the dark square.
I currently have the following code:
https://jsfiddle.net/brampower/tw08fdhf/

```
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
        min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if (max == min) {
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    } else {
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch (max) {
            case r:
                h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
                break;
            case g:
                h = (b - r) / d + 2;
                break;
            case b:
                h = (r - g) / d + 4;
                break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return ({
        h: h,
        s: s,
        l: l,
    });
}

function solve_darkest(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image();
  image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    image.src = url;

    image.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    var WIDTH = image.width;
    var HEIGHT = image.height;

        canvas.width  = WIDTH;
        canvas.height = HEIGHT;

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        var pixel = 0;
        var darkest_pixel_lightness = 100;
        var darkest_pixel_location = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4, pixel++) {
            red = imgData.data[i + 0];
            green = imgData.data[i + 1];
            blue = imgData.data[i + 2];
            alpha = imgData.data[i + 3];

      if (alpha < 230) {
        continue;
      }
      console.log(Math.floor(pixel / WIDTH) + " ", i % WIDTH);


            var hsl = rgbToHsl(red, green, blue);
            var lightness = hsl.l;

            if (lightness < darkest_pixel_lightness) {
                darkest_pixel_lightness = lightness;
                darkest_pixel_location = pixel;
            }
        }

        var y = Math.floor(darkest_pixel_location / WIDTH);
        var x = darkest_pixel_location % WIDTH;

        callback(x,y);
    };
}

image_url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYX1j.png';
solve_darkest(image_url, function(x, y) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('x: '+x+' y: '+y);
    }, 100);
});
```

But it is not giving me the results I am expecting. It loops through all the pixels and then returns the x and y of the darkest pixel. However, it appears that the darkest pixel doesn't reside in the dark square area.
What can I do to make it return the x,y of the middle of the darker square?

Comment: Maybe the darkest pixel isn't actually in the square?

Comment: Correct, which is why I think I'd need to take a sample of, say, 10x10 or 20x20 and then see the overall darkness of that area, and then send back the x and y of the middle of the darkest area. I am just not sure how to go about this, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm. What you **could** do is 'loop' through the image, checking each pixel at a time, storing them in an array. Once you find a pixel that is 'dark' (presumably compared to earlier checked pixels), you could check the 10 previous and 10 next pixels in the array. For vertical checking as well, you could offset `x` many items in the array by however wide the image is.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure where to even begin doing that. It took a long time for me to get to what I currently have, and even now it is not working. Looks like I have a lot of lessons to learn when it comes to JS